# Using a delegate to pass an instance method to an IBOutlet Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, iboutlet

I am wondering how would you go about passing an instance method such as a

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

method to another class using a delegate? Currently I have set up an

```
IBOutlet NSViewController *tableUpdate
```

on the other class and have binded the view to the tablecontroller class.

I was thinking maybe create a protocol and call `[self.tableUpdate protocol method]`. Is this possible? I have been reading up on protocols and cannot find a clear and concise example for this use case. Any help  is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you do not access the tableView from a class other than the class that created it. You should have a controller class that owns the tableview and provides an interface such as `newDataAvailable` or something like that. In other words, hide the implementation detail of using a tableView and just have the two objects communicate about what has happened.

Comment: Isn't that what I have done though. I have a viewcontroller controlling the tableView and I want that controller to send data back through the outlet tableUpdate. I created a function called reloadTableData for the interface